# Jetty: Detect if Webapp failed to start

Tags: servlets, jetty

I am launching an embedded Jetty instance containing a single webapp. The webapp launches on start-up. **I'd like to know how to detect if the Webapp's contextInitialized throws an exception.**

When the webapp throws an exception, [Server.start()](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) doesn't and server.isRunning() returns true. Is there a way for me to listen for webapp exceptions from outside the container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Setting `WebAppContext.setThrowUnavailableOnStartupException(true)` causes the server to propagate any webapp exceptions to `Server.start()`. I'm guessing one could also invoke `WebAppContext.isFailed()` after server start-up to check individual contexts.

Comment: In Jetty 9 method `WebAppContext.setThrowUnavailableOnStartupException(true)`, but you can check if webapp is available with `webappContext.isAvailable()` and the possible error on startup with `webappContext.getUnavailableException()`.

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager requestAppGoal method do not re-throw the exception it just logs the exception stack trace generated by org.eclipse.jetty.webappWebAppContext.java.doStart(). So, how can it propagate to Server.start()?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this trying to make this work for a *non-embedded* solution. In case anyone is in a similar boat, the solution for that case is to create `WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="throwUnavailableOnStartupException">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

The server will fail startup on an exception as expected.

Comment: Note: that DTD is invalid for Jetty 9.3+.